# How to use a wireless remote shutter release with flash?

Tags: flash, remote, wireless-triggers

I'm about to buy a wireless remote shutter release. However, all shutter releases that I saw so far are attached to the flash shoe and cover the build-in flash. Are there wireless remote shutter releases out there that allow me to use an external or build-in flash?

Thanks,
Ralf

Comment: Thank you for asking, I was wondering the same exact thing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

they're designed to fit on the hotshoe because that's a handy place. It's pretty much the only place to mount stuff on cameras. You don't HAVE to mount it there. Velcro, rubber band, straps, use whatever to mount it where ever. Depends on how you're mounting your camera.

Comment: Ahhh, I though they put it on the hot-shoe because of power-supply reason. So I guess the sender has a battery. Thanks for that!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness -- this is the perfect application for one of those rinky-dink little "flash brackets" (you know the ones) that are so cheap, flimsy and small that they're completely useless for an actual flash. I used to use one for the auto thyristor sensor for a slaved flash when using on-camera flash for fill.

Comment: @Stan Rogers hits nail on head - if your local camera stor has used equipment for sale you can often pick up an appropriate "flash bracket" used for about $10

Answer (score 1):

Many cameras have an optical wireless remote release sensor. An optical remote is just a couple of $$'s (like this [example](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/jianisi-digital-slr-remote-for-canon-5577)) and requires no special receiver to be attached to the camera. Of course, you generally need line of sight to the camera, or at least a good reflection from nearby walls or ceiling.

Comment: Out of 311 current cameras, only 24 feature a wireless (infrared actually) remote sensor, so I would say it is far from *most*.

Comment: @Itai - This is certainly surprising. Do you include all P&S in this count? If so, then definitely I am biased towards the bigger cameras. The OP talks about a camera with a hot-shoe that has a socket for a cable release. I assumed this is a SLR or a bridge compact. Do you suggest that out of these only the minority can be triggered optically? What camera has a cable release but no IR sensor?

Comment: @yasp - Excuse my lack of imagination ;) you said *most cameras* so simply wanted to dispel that. There are 70 current cameras with hot-shoe (http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?hotshoe=1) and **only 18 have wireless remote sensors** (see bottom of Refine Result box on page linked above). **40 of them support a wired remote**, keep in mind that some models support both, so the number of cameras with neither is greater than 12.

Comment: @Itai - I stand corrected, and definitely surprised. I'll fix my post to reflect that, replacing "most" with "many".

Comment: I think that search is incomplete. The Nikon D7000 has wireless infrared support, for example.